# Where to find SolidMechanicsExtendedStrain and SolidMechanicsExtendedStress?

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method, solidmechanics

The introduction to solid mechanics from Wolfram:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html#775646651

mentions two functions:

PDEModels`SolidMechanicsExtendedStrain

PDEModels`SolidMechanicsExtendedStress

but does not mention where to find them. They are not contained in "PDEModels`". Does anybody know where these functions can be found?

Comment: It looks like its not implemented yet.  Reminds me of esc del2 esc.  That was in the documentation for years before it actually started working in version 13.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: MMA version 13.2 Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

That's a bug and fixed in (the upcoming) version 13.3. Sorry about that.

Comment: When is 13.3 going to be released?

Comment: @user13892 in a few days I guess.

Comment: Already live in the cloud.